# Using slim's Container::get('settings') versus accessing array directly

Tags: php, slim

The following three approaches produce the same effect.  Which approach should be used?  Are there times one should be used over another?

```
function getConfig() {
    $config=parse_ini_file(__DIR__.'/../config.ini',true);
    $config['directories']['base']=dirname(__DIR__);
    return $config;
}
$c = new \Slim\Container(['settings' => [
    'displayErrorDetails'=>true,
    'addContentLengthHeader'=>false,
    'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware'=>true,
    'config'=>getConfig()
]]);

$config=getConfig();
$c['pdo'] = function ($c) use($config){
    $db1 = $c['settings']['config']['mysql'];
    $db2 = $c->get('settings')['config']['mysql'];
    $db3 = $config['mysql'];
    return new \PDO(/* ... */);
};
```

Side note.  Is it recommended to use a separate settings property for any application settings as I did with "config" to reduce the chance of conflicts with Slim's internal settings (i.e. `httpVersion`, `responseChunkSize`, `outputBuffering`, `determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware`, `displayErrorDetails`, `addContentLengthHeader`, `routerCacheFile`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get all settings just call the `get()` method like this:

```
$settings = $container->get('settings');
```

Comment: Thanks DanielO, however, this really doesn't answer my question.  Whether the container is first populated or the app initiated is another question, and I have concluded (not saying I am right, but just that this is how I will proceed) that the container should be populated first.

Comment: Well sorry, but the "correct" order should be: 1. init settings, 2. create App instance with settings, 3. init App container dependencies with the settings.

Comment: I've seen both used, and I don't think one is necessarily better than the other as they do the same thing.  The approach I showed just first completes the container before passing to the app, and yours partially populates the container before passing, then gets that container, and then completes populating it.  Here are two that like the way I showed: http://discourse.slimframework.com/t/containers-app-getcontainer-vs-new-slim-container/1094/4?u=notioncommotion

Comment: Regardless, my question related to your line of code `$settings = $container->get('settings');` which could be re-written as `$settings = $container['settings'];`  I think your version is more intuitive, however, the example implementation (i.e. https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/tutorial/first-app.html) shows the other approach.

Comment: You could use the array syntax for the container, but be careful. I think the array syntax feature will be dropped in Slim 4, because it's not PSR-11 compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the words of warning.  I will go forward standardizing to using the `get` method.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer by including a single line to the effect that one should use the `get` method?  Your comment answered my question but not currently your answer.  Thanks

Comment: Well, I liked your earlier content as well, and meant to only "add" and not replace everything :)

Comment: If you've used the Slim 4 skeleton, the way to get the settings from the container is:
`$settings = $container->get(SettingsInterface::class);`